# pythonでファイルを開こうとしたらPermissionError: Permission deniedというエラーが出てしまいました

Tags: python, tkinter

pythonでボタンを押すと指定されたファイルが開く簡潔なランチャーを作っていたのですが、指定したファイルを開こうとするとPermissionError: Permission deniedというエラーが出てしまいます。
どうすれば解決するでしょうか。OSはWindowsで管理者権限でアクセスしてます。
ちなみにコード全文は以下の通りです。

```
class Frame(Tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=1000, height=1000)
        self.master.title("簡易ランチャー")

        la = Tk.Button(self, text = "novel", command = self.f_open)
        la.pack()

        lb = Tk.Button(self, text = "programs", command = self.f_open)
        lb.pack()

    def f_open(self):
        f = open(r"C:\Users\hoge\Documents\python programs", "r", encoding="utf-8")
        f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Frame()
    f.pack()
    f.mainloop()
```

Comment: まずは、コードをトラブルが再現する最小限のものにして下さい。例えば、open の行だけでエラーになるのであれば、tkinter は関係ないと分かりますし、回答してくれる人も増えるでしょう。また、openしようとしているファイルはどういった物ですか？エディタなどで開く事は出来ていますか？

Comment: 始めたばかりでやり方が分からず、申しわけありません。次からはそうしようとおもいます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もしかして、「開く」と言うのは、ファイルを読み取りたいわけではなく、Windows上でフォルダを開いたりアプリケーションを実行したい、ということですか？
Windowsであればos.startfileを使うのが分かりやすいと思います。

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\Program Files\....\foobar.exe')
os.startfile('http://www.google.com/')
```

http://docs.python.jp/2/library/os.html#os.startfile をご参照下さい。

Windows以外では、

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['open', 'filename'])
```

がお勧めです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その通りです。無事やりたいことが出来ました。また、つたない質問をして申し訳ありませんでした。